# add a plus sign next to positive value on excel report

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

I use this line to formate my excel cell

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D12')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("0%");
```

if the value is negative, excel takes care of that and display the value with a negative sign next to it.
like : `-12`

How can I change my above code so that the value sign will shows up next to value even if the value is positive?

I mean if the value is positive I will see 12, but I want to change my code to be display `+12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format `+0;-0;0` works in Excel (*Shows + for positive, - for negative, 0 for 0*)

So try this

```
setFormatCode("+0;-0;0")
```

Comment: Please note, that the format should be `"+"0;"-"0;0` instead of `+0;-0;0`. Otherwise you will have double negative sign (e.g. `--4`) in some software (e.g. in `Numbers` app on mac).